# Iphone 6s, question about recovering photos from iCloud on to the new phone. Please help.

Tags: iphone

I got a new phone and I have everything backed up on iCloud. Everything restored (apps, phone contacts, etc.) exceptfor the photos. How do I get them from iCloud on to my new phone? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you did a restore from iCloud backup, your photos should appear.

If not, go to settings -> Your name -> iCloud -> Photos and turn on the following:

iCloud Photo Library & Keep and Download Originals

If the photos dont show, check your iCloud storage for photo backup size and iCloud backups. If you have an iCloud backup that has a favorable date, then restoring that could be in your favor.